# Control flow of logger used in android samples

Tags: android, logging

I liked the way the logger is used in Android samples and want to implement the same in my App. But I am finding it difficult to understand the control flow. Can someone help me in understanding it.

I am refering the RecyclerView Sample.

Download Link :https://developer.android.com/downloads/samples/RecyclerView.zip

Screenshot of the Project Structure :

[image: The screenshot of project structure]

Edit1 : I am not getting what is actually happening here where it says *For piping: The next node to receive Log data...*. And how the messages are printed on console as well as UI.

Code section from LogWrapper class :

```
// For piping:  The next node to receive Log data after this one has done its work.
private LogNode mNext;

/**
 * Returns the next LogNode in the linked list.
 */
public LogNode getNext() {
    return mNext;
}

/**
 * Sets the LogNode data will be sent to..
 */
public void setNext(LogNode node) {
    mNext = node;
}
```

I want to know the relationship between various classes under logger package and how the control flows between them when we call Log.d() from activity, fragment or adapter.

Comment: Why is it better than standard logger? Did you try [Timber](https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber)?

Comment: @MaximG : No I didn't know about it. I'll have a look at it. In this sample, by using this logger they are printing the log in UI(TextViews). I am thinking of using the same concept and redirect the logs to a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Piping implemented via link list.

In `MainActivity.initializeLogging()` you populate this list.

LogWrapper -> MessageOnlyLogFilter -> LogView

All those classes implemented interface LogNode (can print) and list alike behaviour (node and move to the next).

LogWrapper sends all messages to the standard logger, than if any node exists it will pipe message (in our case MessageOnlyLogFilter).

MessageOnlyLogFilter strips everything except the message and pushes to the next node (LogView).

LogView extends TextView and prints logs on a screen.

Comment: I want to know the relationship between the various classes under logger package and how the control flows between them when We call Log.d() from the activity, fragment or adapter. How it prints on console as well as on the UI. I'll update my question with what is confusing me.

Comment: Thanks, I got it now. The whole purpose of these classes is chaining the message. The first node in the chain is `LogWrapper` which prints the message on console using android.util.log.println() and then passes the message to the next node in the chain i.e., `MessageOnlyLogFilter`. It strips out everything (TAG, package name, time, etc.) except the message and passes this message to the next node i.e., `LogView`. LogView displays the message in the TextView and returns.